# Displaying data of something with composite key

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am making an MVC application and I have 3 entities, `Year`, `Week` and `Day`. I am using composite keys in `Week` and `Day`.

Here are the models, first, the `Year` model:

```
namespace Utility3.Models
{
    public class Year
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key]
        public int YearID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Week> Weeks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Week` model:

```
namespace Utility3.Models
{
    public class Week
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int WeekID { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int YearID { get; set; }

        public virtual Year year { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Day> Days { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the `Day` model:

```
namespace Utility3.Models
{
    public class Day
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int DayID { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int WeekID { get; set; }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
        public int YearID { get; set; }

        public float Reading1 { get; set; }
        public float Reading2 { get; set; }

        public virtual Week Weeks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My question is about displaying the data with the html. In the Index page for the `Week` controller, at the bottom of the code there is this:

```
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
```

I do not know what to put in for the `/* id=item.PrimaryKey */` part. How do you go about that part with composite keys?

Answer (score 0):

That's because there's nothing you *can* put there that'll work. If you're using composite keys then you need to pass *all* the key values, and use them all to look up your object.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  yearId = item.YearID, weekId = item.WeekID, dayId = item.DayID })
```

Which means you'd have to have an action that can accept these parameters:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int yearId, int weekId, int dayId)
{
    // do something
}
```

And then, of course, a route to get to this action:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Foo",
    "Foo/{action}/{yearId}/{weekId}/{dayId}",
    new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index" }
);
```

Of course, all your problems would go away if you simply *don't use composite keys*. There's just no good reason to, and all it does is add complexity to your code as the above shows. Why in the world should I need to know all that information just to look up a row in a table? Just give it a standard auto-incrementing primary key. Also, even if you insist on using a composite key, it's a *hugely* bad idea to use *foreign keys* as the components of that composite key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I figured it out and have pretty much the same as your first two segments of code, but I did not need the route? I need to know all that information and I am only learning this stuff. An auto-incrementing primary key did not work for what I wanted.

Comment: Well, yeah, it'll work without the route. All the parameters will just end up as part of a query string off the best matching route it can find.